# Slick slider for post doesn't display anything

Tags: wp-query, jquery, slideshow

I want to make a testimonial slider with slick from   https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. i use WP_Query for get the post with specific category. the slick works finde but it doesn't show the content.
This is my PHP code:

```
   <div  class=" container">
                    <div id="testimoni-carousel" class='row testimoni-carousel' dir="rtl">

                   <?php 
                         $args = array(
                            'post_type'=> 'post',
                            'category_name' => 'komentar'
                          );
                          $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                          if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                              while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
                              $query->the_post();
                              ?>
                              <div class='text-center testimoni-teks col-12'>
                                <h2 class='text-white'><?php the_title() ?></h2>   
                                <div class='text-white'><?php the_content() ?></div>

                              </div>
                                <?php
                              }
                              wp_reset_postdata();
                          }
                   ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this my JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#testimoni-carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 0):

look at this example structure :

```
/**
* Section Servises
*/
$servises_info = new WP_query('pagename=правни-услуги');
if ($servises_info -> have_posts() ) :
    while ( $servises_info -> have_posts() ) : $servises_info -> the_post();
                                            // look hire below
                $relayted_post = new WP_query('cat=2&order=ASC');
                /* Start the Loop two */
                while($relayted_post -> have_posts()): $relayted_post -> the_post();
                    $servises_data = get_the_content();

                // make hire you're things

                endwhile;
               // End the posts Servises Loop - loop 2 
     endwhile; 
     // End the page Servises Loop -loop 1

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
// End the servises  info section
```

i recomend to use ID's no names when accses categorys,taxonomis.

And also you have mistakes hire :

```
<h2 class='text-white'><?php the_title() mising closing row -> ";" ?></h2>   
<div class='text-white'><?php the_content() mising closing row -> ";" ?></div>
```